# best practice for trigger a method by user's input in angular2

Tags: angular, event-handling, user-input

I have this scenario: expecting an user's input and use that to `_http.get()` from server.
I have tried using `keyup` event, but can't manage. Any recommendation is much appreciated.

My template:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="workOrder" (keyup)="populate()" placeholder="{{ 'FIELDS.PMS_IFR_WO' | translate }}"/>
</div>
```

My ts file:

```
populate(){
  console.log(this.workOrder);
  this._lookup.getIcrData().subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `ngModelChange`:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngModel]="workOrder" (ngModelChange)="populate($event)" placeholder="{{ 'FIELDS.PMS_IFR_WO' | translate }}"/>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
populate(value: any){
  console.log(value);
  this._lookup.getIcrData().subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
  });
}
```

Comment: thank you! It is good but not quite there yet. if user inputs the number 999 it triggers populate 3 times. in the end i want to use only the final value (ex 999) and would like to know how to trigger an method with final value as argument

Comment: @ClaudiuUngureanu Check out Prithivi Raj's answer on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 1):

`ngModelChange` is usually a good option

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
    [(ngModel)]="workOrder" 
    (ngModelChange)="populate()" 
    placeholder="{{ 'FIELDS.PMS_IFR_WO' | translate }}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try RxJs, if you looking for a best practice. [check this angular documentation](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#the-searchterms-rxjs-subject)
Template

```
<input #searchBox type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="workOrder" (keyup)="populate(searchBox.value)" placeholder="{{ 'FIELDS.PMS_IFR_WO' | translate }}"/>
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { of }         from 'rxjs/observable/of';

import {
   debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap
 } from 'rxjs/operators';

searchResult : Observable<any>;
private searchTerms = new Subject<string>();

ngOnInit(): void {
this.searchResult = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
  debounceTime(300),

  // ignore new term if same as previous term
  distinctUntilChanged(),

  // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
  switchMap((term: string) =>   this._lookup.getIcrData(term)),
);
}

populate(term: string){
this.searchTerms.next(term);
}
```